# panel controls not resizing according to window screen resolution

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel

I am trying to add JPanel on JFrame . JPanel is being  designed in netbeans. JPanel is using FreeDesign Layout . The current resolution of the window screen is 1024*768 but as i change the resolution to 800*600 the controls on the panel does not resize automatically according to the new resolution of the window screen.

> How is this possible to make the panel controls according to the new resolution    window

Comment: Use a different layout manager?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.